# Is there a temperature sensor which triggers voltage output upon breaching a temperature threshold?

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, temperature

Is there a temperature sensor which will output a certain voltage if the temperature is below a certain degrees? e.g. Output 5v if temperature is < 0°C and output 0v if > 0°C.

I'm trying to figure out how to detect when a temperature drops below freezing and I'm unable to utilize 1-bit bus, single bus and one-wire setups for temperature inputs. Only a "1" or a "0" digital input is usable.

Comment: Is that the whole system? Or can this be a programmable device which outputs this signal?

Comment: There are several that fit your need. Try the parametric searches of various sensor manufacturers.

Comment: I guess either a programmable sensor or just a fixed one would work. I'm just confused about the correct terminology that I'm trying to describe in the question for a threshold detector.

Comment: You are essentially describing a "thermostat". These can be electronic or mechanical. If you search on that term you should find much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for threshold detection, ideally with some hysteresis.

You can program the [TMP175](http://www.ti.com/product/tmp175) to set/clear its single alert pin at specific high/low temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

A bimetallic switch (commonly called a thermostat) is the answer. The switch contact may be a pair of contacts directly on the bimetallic coil, or it may be a mercury switch which triggers when it reaches a certain tilt angle, but the basic temperature sensing mechanism is the same.

Some years ago it was possible to get such thermostats in very compact form for sensing overtemperatures on pc boards, but these have probably gone out of use due to cheap semiconductor sensors. It would make sense that there might be a specialty market for freeze sensing, but I'm not aware of any specific products.